# SWFUpload what happens after file select?

Tags: php, javascript, swfupload

I'm lost here. I'm trying to set up a simple file upload, handled by SWFUpload. After file selection nothing happens. I don't see a request being sent, and there is nothing in my console. Is the swf object supposed to call my upload_url page immediately?

```
        var swfu,jobForm;
        var j = jQuery.noConflict();
        j(window).load(function() {
            jobForm = j('.admin-atomic-form form');
            swfu = new SWFUpload({
                upload_url : "URL/upload.php",
                flash_url : "URL/swfupload.swf",
                file_size_limit : "20 MB",
                file_types : "*.doc;*.pdf;*.rtf;*docx;*.jpg;",
                //file_types_description : "All Files",
                file_upload_limit : "1",
                button_placeholder_id : "swfuploader",
                button_image_url : "URL/file-browse.png",
                button_width: 100,
                button_height: 30,
                upload_start_handler : uploadStart,
                upload_success_handler : uploadSuccess
            }); 
            //jobForm.form.submit(function(ev){ev.preventDefault()})
        });

        function uploadStart(){
            //.submit()
            console.log(this,'start');
        };
        function uploadSuccess(){
            //form.submit()
            console.log('success');
        }
```

Comment: Did you purposely comment out .submit() and form.submit()?

Comment: Those are my event functions as I was exploring functionality and should have no affect on SWFUpload's core functionality. From what I gather, they should merely trigger on said events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SWFUploadObj.startUpload();` needs to be fired and that's what initiated the POST request to the specified upload_url. If this method is fired by some default setting, it certainly wasn't doing it for me.

Here is an example of a few of my functions:

```
// Bound to file_queued_handler : sets a flag that there is a file waiting to upload 
function swfuFileQueued(file){
    resumeQueued = true;
    $j('#browseFile').val(file.name);
}


//Bound to form submit event:
//a successful upload will submit this form again once the success response with the server-moved and renamed filename comes back from the file upload handling script

function swfuFormSubmit(ev){
    if(uploadSuccess){
        return true;
    } else {
        if(resumeQueued == true){
            ev.preventDefault();
            swfuUploadStart(); // see next function
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}

function swfuUploadStart(){
    try {
        swfu.startUpload(); // <-- The actual method that begins the file upload request
    } catch (e) {
    }
    return false;
}

function swfuProgress(){ ...
function swfuError(){ ...
function swfuSuccess(){ 
    //update input element containing filename or id to send with form
    //update a status box with "Success"
    //uploadSuccess = true 
    //form.submit() once more, this time uploadSuccess will tell the function to continue on and actually submit itself
```

Useful URL to understand SWFUpload process : http://www.dconstructing.com/2010/07/08/making-swfupload-work

Answer (score 0):

starting to upload a file is a two step process: 1. you select a file (which then populates a path in an input box), 2. you must submit the form to begin the actual upload.

I'm assuming you're not doing step 2, since in your code, you have commented out `form.submit()`

please uncomment this line: `//jobForm.form.submit(function(ev){ev.preventDefault()})`

then after you select a file, submit the form.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no input being inserted into the DOM after select.

Comment: no no, you're misunderstanding. that "select file" button contains a hidden input already which is where the file path goes after you select something.